# How to display \r\n as actual new line in command prompt?

Tags: python, command-prompt

I have this Python code which goes like

```
output = str(check_output(["./listdevs.exe", "-p"]))
print (output)
```

When running this Python code in the Command Prompt, I'm met with this output

```
b'80ee:0021\r\n8086:1e31\r\n'
```

Instead of the above output, I would like to display it where the \r
\n is replaced with an actual new line where it would look like

```
'80ee:0021
8086:1e31'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is in bytes. So you have to call `decode` method to convert the byte object to string object.

```
>>> print(output.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.7+, you can pass `text=True` to `subprocess.check_output` to obtain the results as a string.

Prior to 3.7 you can use `universal_newlines=True`.  [`text` is just an alias for `universal_newlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

```py
output = str(subprocess.check_output(["./listdevs.exe", "-p"], text=True))
```